# "Serial Loader Device is missing" during Convert Programming File with Quartus Prime

Tags: intel, fpga, quartus, intel-fpga

I try to convert multiple SRAM object (.sof) files to one JTAG indirect configuration file (.jic) using Quartus Prime, however I always receive the following error message.

> Serial Flash Loader device is missing

[image: Error Message and input files to convert]

I use the Cyclone 10 LP Evaluation Kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from defining, which files to convert, also the flash loader itself has to be defined.

1. Click on Flash Loader
   [image: Adding a Flash Loader for a device]
2. Click on Add Device
3. Select the device family and device name in the upcoming window. (in the screenshot the right device family and name for the Cyclone 10 LP evaluation board is selected)
   [image: Selecting the device family and device name]